# How to print the moving hourglass?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in C programming.
Here is my code.  But I don't know how to fix it. It is quite weird. Something is wrong. Please help me to fix it! Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, n, r, c, sp;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\n");

    n = num;

    for (r = 1; r <= num; r++)
    {
        for (sp = 1; sp < r; sp++)
            printf(" ");

        for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
            printf("**");
        n--;
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Please learn how to format questions correctly and don't post pictures of text

Comment: "There is some problem in my lower part of hourglass." What is the problem? What is the output? How does it differ from desired output? If you can describe the  error in prose it might help you detect the error in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always draw neat little pictures first and analyze:

```
assume mid_height = 5
           height = 2 * mid_height - 1

               +---------------------------- = 0 ... height - 1
               |        +------------------- = line < mid_height ? line : height - line - 1
               |        |        +---------- = height + 1 - spaces * 2
               |        |        |       +-- = mid_height <= line && line < height - 1
               |        |        |       |
               |    leading   stars/   points
1234567890    line   spaces   points    line  
**********     0        0       10       no
 ********      1        1        8       no
  ******       2        2        6       no
   ****        3        3        4       no
    **         4        4        2       no
   *..*        5        3        4       si
  *....*       6        2        6       si
 *......*      7        1        8       si
**********     8        0       10       no
```

After that it's just a writing exercise:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int mid_height;
    while (printf("Please enter the mid height of the hourglass: "),
           scanf("%d", &mid_height) != 1 || mid_height < 1) {
        fputs("Input error!\n\n", stderr);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');

    int height = 2 * mid_height - 1;

    for (int line = 0; line < height; ++line) {
        int spaces = line < mid_height ? line : height - line - 1;
        int points_line = mid_height <= line && line < height - 1;
        for (int w = 0; w < height + 1 - spaces; ++w) {
            int points = points_line && w != spaces && w != height - spaces;
            putchar(w < spaces ? ' ' : points ? '.' : '*');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Please enter the mid height of the hourglass: 5

**********
 ********
  ******
   ****
    **
   *..*
  *....*
 *......*
**********
```

Comment: @kiranBiradar i hate drawing :/